# Stream extracting from std::stringstream with spaces

Tags: c++

I have this template function that gets an element from an `std::map` as a string, converts it to generic `T` through `std::stringstream operator>>` and returns it.

However the extraction operator only extracts the first word in the stream.

I have tried `.str()`, but for a template function it won't do. I have also tried `ss >> std::noskipws >> result;` but it does not seem to return valid data.

```cpp
template<typename T>
T CConfig::get(const char *setting)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << this->m_settings[setting];
    // this->m_settings[setting] = "this is a test"

    T result;
    ss >> result;
    // result = "this"

    return result;
}
```

My expectation is that if m_settings[setting] is `"this is a test"`, the same string will be returned in my `get` function. And at the same time, I don't want to break the template by hardcoding `ss.str()` and using a different function for strings.

Comment: If your goal is to read a line of text terminated by a newline, this is what `std::getline()` is for. `>>` is the wrong tool for the wrong job.

Comment: `std::getline()` breaks the behavior when I use for example `get<int>`

Comment: Then make a specialization for `get<std::string>` that uses `std::getline()`

Comment: @0x499602D2 You should write an _answer_; don't give the solution in the comments where it cannot be properly peer reviewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways:

1. Like I said in my comment, you can specialize the function `get<std::string>` and call `std::getline()` from there.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   T CConfig::get(const char* settings) {
     std::istringstream stream(m_settings[settings]);
     T t; assert(stream >> t);
     return t;
   }

   template<>
   std::string CConfig::get<std::string>(const char* settings) {
     std::istringstream stream(m_settings[settings]);
     T t; assert((std::getline(stream, t)));
     return t;
   }
   ```

   The cons of this approach is that it causes code-duplication.
2. Delegate to a helper function that uses a primary and specialized overload.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   T CConfig::get(const char* settings) {
     T t;
     assert(
       do_get(std::istringstream(m_settings[settings]) >> std::skipws, t);
     );
     return t;
   }

   template<typename T>
   bool do_get(std::istringstream& stream, T& data) {
     return stream >> data;
   }

   template<>
   bool do_get(std::istringstream& stream, std::string& data) {
     return std::getline(stream, data);
   }
   ```
3. If you have [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) then just use `if constexpr`:

   ```
   template<class T>
   T CConfig::get(const char* settings) {
     T t;
     std::istringstream stream(m_settings[settings]);
     if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
       assert((std::getline(stream, t)));
     } else {
       assert(stream >> t);
     }
     return t;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide exactly what you want the behaviour to be for strings. If you want to extract a whole line, you can use `std::getline()`. Or in this case, perhaps just `return this->m_settings[setting];`.

Whatever you end up doing, the solution is to put the variant behaviour into a *specialisation* for `get<std::string>`.

Just be careful that the specialised behaviour doesn't deviate too far from that of the primary code, because that might be confusing to your users (which includes yourself!).

Comment: About specialization, how come this doesn't work? `template <> std::string get(const char *setting)` - I cannot find examples for this usage on cppreference unfortunately

Comment: @shavit A specialisation for string would be `template<> std::string get<std::string>(const char *setting)`

Comment: @shavit It has [plenty of examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) if you simply Google "cppreference template specialisation". Alternatively, turn to the page in your C++ book about template specialisations